# Canvas on frames & Switching between frames using buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newbie to python and Tkinter, please mind my silly mistakes if any.
The code I am attaching is a generalised and simpler version in order to get and test simply. Once I am ok with it, will prepare the application code. 
I have two frames, who have their parent as the root geometry window.
Each frame has many canvases drawn in my main application, but I am drawing  only one sample rectangle in my question for the sake of making it short.
My problem is while I draw two canvas on two different frames, on running the program, both appear simultaneously.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import *

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("550x550")

Crel='groove'
Cbw=3
h=50
w=50

#####Frame 1 & rectangle Canvas drawn########
Cparent=ttk.Frame(root,height=200,width=200)
Cparent.pack()
hallname=tk.Canvas(Cparent,height=h,width=w,relief=str(Crel),
                   borderwidth=int(Cbw))
hallname.place(x=150,y=150)

#####Frame 2 & rectangle Canvas drawn########
Cparent2=ttk.Frame(root,height=200,width=200)
Cparent2.pack()
hallname1=tk.Canvas(Cparent2,height=h,width=w,relief=str(Crel),
                    borderwidth=int(Cbw))
hallname1.place(x=30,y=30)

#####Function to switch frames########
def pushbut(obj):
    obj.tkraise(obj)

#####Buttons size and font#######
buttonnamefont=font.Font(root,family="Helvetica",size=10,weight="bold") 
Details=Button(root,text='Details',font=buttonnamefont,
                command=lambda:pushbut(Cparent))
Overview=Button(root,text='Overview',font=buttonnamefont,
                command=lambda:pushbut(Cparent2))
Overview.place(x=300,y=520)
Details.place(x=100,y=520)

Cparent.tkraise()
root.update()
```

If i try to show one frame using tkraise function, still the other frame also shows up.

About switching frames, I have made two buttons,and tried to switch between frames using lamba function, however failed to do so.
Please let me know for minute and idiotic mistakes if made by me;)

Comment: To use tkraise trick you have to use `grid()`, not `pack()`, and set the row and column to the same grid cell for both frames.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. This question is really hard to read.

Comment: Did it @BryanOakley,...sorry ..my mistake.

Comment: Will try it for sure @Novel

Comment: Sorted it out.....how idiotic of me..;(.....What a wrong way to pass the frame through pushbut func. Anyways..made it hrough.

Comment: sorted it out, best option being prepare machine as a canvas instead of hall canvas. The class is thus one consisting of initialisation of canvas, with the size just passed as parameters. Thus different canvases are created as onjects with varying sizes. They can be thus acessed individually.